# Bloom Hulk and Kronch Wrangler

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When you have a [Kronch Wrangler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKronch%20Wrangler%5d) on the battlefield

> Whenever a creature with power 4 or greater enters the battlefield under your control, put a +1/+1 counter on Kronch Wrangler.

and a [Bloom Hulk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBloom%20Hulk%5d) enters the battlefield

> When Bloom Hulk enters the battlefield, proliferate.

which ETB effect goes onto the stack first?

Are the triggers simultaneous, so I as an active player can choose to give my Kronch Wrangler a counter, and then proliferate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You chose the orders your triggers go on the stack.  If you want to give you Kronch Wrangler 2 counters, you would put the proliferate trigger on the stack first, thus putting it on the bottom of the stack, thus causing it to resolve after Kronch Wrangler's trigger.

> 603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities they control on the stack in any order they choose.